# Does DBUnit change the actual state of the database?

Tags: spring, integration-testing, dbunit, spring-test-dbunit

For example, after I setup a datasource to the actual database and use @DatabaseSetup to set it to a state, which of the following happens?

1) DBUnit connect to the actual database, delete everything, insert records specified in @DatabaseSetup, test the cases and then roll back.

2) DBUnit somehow create an in-memory database based on the datasource, setup the in-memory database. Nothing is changed in the actual database.

3) Magic.

How does the DBUnit work? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

DBUnit does exactly what you ask it to do. If you connect it to the real database, then yes, it will be acting on the real database. If you tell it to act on an in-memory database, then that's what it will do.

If you get it to do a CLEAN_INSERT, then it will wipe all of the data in all tables specified in the dataset you're asking it to load, it'll then load the dataset, then it will remove the loaded dataset. The data it wiped at the start will not be put back in place.

If you're using DBUnit for testing, you generally would not point it at the real (i.e. production) database. Instead you'd create a copy of some sort and point it at that. That copy could be a real instance of your DB, something in-memory, it could be populated with dummy data or a copy of the real data.